# function isAlphabet will take letters and return true if the order of the letters matches the order in the alphabet, otherwise false

Tags: javascript, arrays, character, sequence, alphabetical

I need to implement such `isAlphabet` function that will take letters and return `true` if the order of the letters matches the order in the alphabet, otherwise `false`:

```
isAlphabet ('abc') === true
isAlphabet ('aBc') === true
isAlphabet ('abd') === false // - there is c after b
isAlphabet ('a') === true
isAlphabet ('') === false // - task not completed
isAlphabet ('abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz') === false // - j goes after i
isAlphabet ('tuvwxyz') === true
isAlphabet ('XYZ') === true
isAlphabet ('mnoprqst') === false // - q goes before r
```

My code:

```
function isAlphabet(letters) {
    // write code here
    const char = letters.toLowerCase();
    for (let i = 0; i < char.length; i++) {
        if (char[i + 1] - char[i] !== 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For input `'abc'`, the function must return `true` but my implementation above returns `false`.

Could you help me to find an error in my code?

---

***Edit***

After having changed the code according to some suggestions to ...

```
function isAlphabet(letters) {
  // write code here
  const ch = letters.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i + 1].charCodeAt() - ch[i].charCodeAt() !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

... the function still errors.

Comment: Do you have a question about this?

Comment: Which test(s) is it erroring on?

Comment: What made you think `!==` (and can you please _stop_ using _strict_ comparison operator when you don't have a solid grasp of the _problem domain_ in the first place? use `!=` -- noone wants to be surprised reading someone elses code), does comparing two subsequent character ordinals? Why `1`? What if you're comparing `'q'` at `i` and `'z'` at `i + 1`? `'q'` comes before `'z'` in the alphabet yet the difference between them, as computed by your expression, is a negative number larger than `1`...

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli Erm, `!==` is the less surprising comparison `!=` is the more surprising one. I'd definitely recommend using strict comparison in almost every case.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli also, what made you think that subtracting two letters as strings results in a negative number?

Comment: hint ... `'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 'b'.charCodeAt(0)` equals `-1` whereas `'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 'c'.charCodeAt(0)` equals `-2` and the result of `'aBc'.toLowerCase().split('')` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli isAlphabet ('abd') === false /// - there is c after b. 1 because the next number of letter code in alphabet is +1 as i understand and i need the line in the alphabet without missings

Comment: @PeterSeliger I have more than this one error. It is an example

Comment: @VladyslavAkopov ... the hint already provides everything one needs for implementing a solution for a case insensitive detection of an alphabetic character sequence.

Comment: I confused comparing ordinals with lexicographical comparison  for a moment there, that`str[i]` would involve. Still, a `<` would suit better there  no?

Comment: @ArmenMichaeli "*Still, a < would suit better there no?*" why exactly?  `"a" < "b"` is `true` but also `"a" < "z"` is `true`. If you get that value you don't actually know if the two are directly adjacent, just that one is after the other but there might be multiple letters in between. How does `<` help?

Comment: @VLAZ True, I didn't catch the order part -- thought this was about relative order, as in return `true` if sequence is sorted, otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comments ...

> *"hint ... `'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 'b'.charCodeAt(0)` equals `-1` whereas `'a'.charCodeAt(0) - 'c'.charCodeAt(0)` equals `-2` and the result of `'aBc'.toLowerCase().split('')` is `['a', 'b', 'c']`."* – Peter Seliger

> > *"@PeterSeliger I have more than this one error. It is an example"* – Vladyslav Akopov

> > > *"@VladyslavAkopov ... the hint already provides everything one needs for implementing a solution for a case insensitive detection of an alphabetic character sequence."* – Peter Seliger

The next following (and commented) code example does prove the above claim.

```js
function isStrictAlphabeticalAscendingSequence(value) {
  // always ensure a string value.
  value = String(value);
  return (
    // ensure a non-empty string value ...
    value.length >= 1 &&
    // ... and ...
    value
      // ... a case insensitive ...
      .toLowerCase()
      // ... character sequence (array) ...
      .split('')
      // ... where ...
      // (the usage of `every` guarantees an early exit)
      .every((char, idx, arr) => {
        let result = true;
        if (idx < arr.length - 1) {
          result =
            // ... each next character is a direct follower
            // of its previous character in a strict
            // alphabetic ascending meaning.
            (arr[idx + 1].charCodeAt(0) - char.charCodeAt(0) === 1);
        }
        return result;
      })
   );
}

[
  'abc',
  'aBc',
  'abd',
  'a',
  '',
  'abcdefghjiklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
  'tuvwxyz',
  'XYZ',
  'mnoprqst',
]
.forEach(value =>
  console
    .log(`'${ value }' => ${ isStrictAlphabeticalAscendingSequence(value) }`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `function isAlphabet(letters) {
  // write code here
  const ch = letters.toLowerCase();

  for (let i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) {
    if (ch[i + 1].charCodeAt() - ch[i].charCodeAt() !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}` still an errors

Comment: At which test cases (the strings provided by the OP together with the OP's expectation) does the OP's latest provided implementation fail? What does the OP think is the source of the (or each single) failure?

Comment: @VladyslavAkopov ... the OP also is encouraged to edit the original question according to the OP's last provided implementation (the one two comments above).

Comment: @VladyslavAkopov ... Regarding the so far sole provided answer / solution are there any questions left?

Comment: No, thank you. I solved problem in my way.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function isAlphabet(letters) {
   
   const lowercaseLetters = letters.toLowerCase();

      // If the string has less than two characters, the order cannot 
 be determined
     // But if the input is a single character, it can be considered 
   an alphabet
    if (lowercaseLetters.length < 2) {
   return lowercaseLetters >= 'a' && lowercaseLetters <= 'z';
 }

   for (let i = 1; i < lowercaseLetters.length; i++) {
         // Compare the ASCII codes of the current letter and the 
  previous one
     if (lowercaseLetters.charCodeAt(i) < 
   lowercaseLetters.charCodeAt(i - 1)) {
  return false;
}
    // Check if the current letter is the same as the previous one
      // If it is, it's not an alphabet sequence

      if (lowercaseLetters[i] === lowercaseLetters[i - 1]) {
  return false;
}
    // Check if there are missing characters in the sequence

   if (lowercaseLetters.charCodeAt(i) - 
       lowercaseLetters.charCodeAt(i- 1) > 1) {
  return false;
}
```

}

return true;
}